# I am Creating a Keyword Driven framework, I want to have 'If' ,'for' and 'for each' loop in excel

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, selenium-ide

I am creating a keyword driven framework using selenium and excel (using apache PoI). I got stuck where I have to handle conditional statement like 'if' condition , for loop, for each loop. 
Let take a below scenario

if I want to click 15 links from the same page(using x-path) as a loop in keyword and Hybrid framework, 
How to loop the x-path in excel sheet
For e.g. 
click on Department links (15 department links)
Get the title of the page after each click 
Navigate back after fetching the title

Can any one suggest me logic of doing this?

Comment: Don't use excel. You will have much more flexibility and power if you design an easy to use API in a programming language like C# or Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the SelBlocks plugin + Flow Control plugin.

Flow Control will add the IF THEN functionality you need.

SelBlocks will allow you to feed your test with external data from an xml.

Getting an XML out of Excel shouldn't be too hard.

Good luck.